# Switch uses both unknown unicast frames and broadcast frames when it can't find MAC address?

Tags: networking

As I read in ICDN1 books about Flooding Frames:

Switches will flood unknown unicast frames when it can not find MAC address in MAC table. It means it is going to forward the frame out off all interfaces to build a correct MAC table. But I don't understand why switches also forward broadcast frames.

This is the passage in the ICDN1 book:

"Flooding Frames

Now again turn your attention to the forwarding process, using Figure 6-6. What do you suppose the switch does with Fred’s first frame in Figure 6-6, the one that occurred when there were no entries in the MAC address table? As it turns out, when there is no matching entry in the table, switches forward the frame out all interfaces (except the incoming interface) using a process called flooding.

Switches flood unknown unicast frames (frames whose destination MAC addresses are not yet in the address table). Flooding means that the switch forwards copies ofthe frame out all ports, except the port on which the frame was received. Ifthe unknown device receives the frame and sends a reply, the reply frame’s source MAC address will allow the switch to build a correct MAC table entry for that device.

**Switches also forward LAN broadcast frames, because this process helps deliver a copy of the frame to all devices in the LAN.**

For example, Figure 6-6 shows the first frame, sent to Barney’s MAC address, just going to Barney. However, in reality, the switch floods this frame out F0/2, F0/3, and F0/4, even though 0200.2222.2222 (Barney) is only offF0/2. The switch does not forward the frame back out F0/1, because a switch never forwards a frame out the same interface on which it arrived.
"

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is?